# Automatic unit test

Tags: c, testing, gcc, embedded, cross-compiling

In our company we develop bare metal embedded software for microcontrollers. Until now we have been using manual unit test on targets or simulators, specially for Renesas microcontrollers (RL78 and RX families). We're planning now to go into automatic unit tests. The idea is to integrate them in our existing CI system.

At this point we've got a dilema. Until now we've been running unit test using the same compiler and target (or simulator) that later has been used to deploy the software into production. We'd like to maintain this approach, as the developers (and everybody) specially appreciate to test and deploy using the same conditions. So the idea would be to take a testing tool/library programmed in C that allows as to compile and run the tests in an embedded environment using a simulator. (Ex. http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity)

But, on the other side, we cope with two upcoming situations that make the dilema arise:

- We're more and more going to Cortex uC, where it's more difficult to get specific simulators to allow automation. (Ex. Renesas RA family)
- Many of the advanced testing tools are developed in C++ and thought for PC environment using gcc/g++ compiler in a x86 architecture, that doesn't match that of the Cortex targets compiled using arm-none-eabi-gcc that we foresee to use.

So, at this point, we're wondering, and this would be my question, what kind of reliability can have unit tests run using gcc if our final target will be a Cortex uC and the binaries will finally be generated using arm-none-eabi-gcc. indirectly I'd be asking for the differences between gcc and arm-none-eabi-gcc when compiling for different targets.

I'd appreciate feedback from someone knowing about gcc internals that could have coped with the same kind of problem.

Thanks in advance,

Ignasi Villagrasa

Comment: `when compiling for different targets.` Huge! Most importantly, `long` is 64bit vs 32bit. In one of my company, we developed a stm32 with an accelerometer. We had a special construct with RPI constantly connected to stm32 on a special board that was shaken using motors also connected to RPI. Integration tests were executed by flashing the STM32 and moving motors to test accelerometer logic, all automatically from gitlab ci/cd.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, simulators are useless, but especially so for production testing. Since it is an embedded system, you want to test software and hardware both - testing software without the intended MCU and hardware in place is just nonsense.

If you insist on using fluffware like simulators or PC "test suites" then realize:

- It is an incomplete test which does not test core functionality of your product.
- It cannot be used to test drivers/hardware-related code, it can only test abstract algorithms.
- It can only be used for development testing, never for production testing.

As for how to correctly test your specific embedded system, it depends on the application and what the product is supposed to do. If you do your projects by the book then you have: Specification, leading to implementation, leading to tests. The sole purpose of a test is to verify that the implementation follows the specification.

So if the specification says that the product should activate 10 relays, you will need to flash the software onto the live MCU on the real PCB and a correctly performed test then verifies that all 10 relays get activated as they should.

This complete and correct product test cannot be done in any other way. So ask yourself if you actually need the incorrect and incomplete simulated test at all. Perhaps your development-related testing should focus on more meaningful things like design reviews, coding standards, static analysis, code reviews etc.